# Perl diamond operator (<>) doesn't handle file name pattern?

Tags: perl

Seems `<>` operator cannot handle file name patterns, like file*.txt. Is there any solution for such need? For example, replace a pattern in files in some name pattern (`perl -i.bak -pe s/p1/p2/g file*.txt`). I am using Windows and cmd.exe also doesn't expand the file name pattern.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Yes, I have the same on mine. "Invalid Argument".

Comment: But you're not *using* the `<>` operator! `print "$_\n" for <file*.txt>` works just fine

Comment: @Borodin: `-p` uses `<>`.

Comment: @Borodin, I am wondering whether this works for in-place replacement (-i)?

Comment: @choroba: That is a very different `<>`!

Comment: @Borodin: The question is what diamond had Thomson in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `glob` operator is used to expand wildcards in file names; see [perldoc -f glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html). However, the built-in one considers whitespace as separators, meaning it won't handle spaces in file names correctly. Replace it with the `:bsd_glob` from [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html). `File::Glob` is a standard module and comes installed with Perl. For a list for standard modules, see [perldoc perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Standard-Modules).

```
use File::Glob qw( :bsd_glob );
@ARGV = map { glob } @ARGV;
```

This is how you can incorporate it in your one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -MFile::Glob=:bsd_glob -pe"BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV } s/p1/p2/g" *.txt
```

Comment: Tip: You can use `if $^O eq 'MSWin32'` to make the code portable.

Comment: Tip: You might prefer `glob` from File::DosGlob.

Answer (score 4):

In *nix, the shell is responsible for expanding wildcards in paths. In MSWin, it's upon the application to do it.

```
perl -i~ -we "@ARGV = glob shift; s/p1/p2/g, print while <>" file*.txt
```

Comment: I was thinking `glob` but hadn't quite got that far. Would `@ARGV = glob ( @ARGV )` be better, as then it'll expand multiple patterns (as would on Unix)? (Or should that be `map { glob $_ } @ARGV `)

Comment: @Sobrique: `glob` takes an expression, not list, so `map` is needed.

Comment: @choroba this looks great. I am wondering how does `s/p2/p2/g,print while<>` work and why the replace happens for each line in the files?

Comment: '-i' says 'inplace edit'. But you've lost the `-p` which implicitly loops, in lieu of an explicit while loop.

Comment: I understand `s/p1/p2/g,print while<>` now, it is the same as `(s/p1/p2/g,print $_) while <>`. Interesting association rule!

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from @choroba, I think using BEGING block to translate the wildchars also works well.

```
perl -i.bak -pe"BEGIN{@ARGV=glob shift}s/p1/p2/g" file*.txt
```

or below works for multiple input patterns:

```
perl -i.bak -pe"BEGIN{@ARGV=map glob,@ARGV}s/p1/p2/g" file*.txt
```